# angularjs $resource result jsonp

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to send a request my server via **JSONP** and get results but I could not do it.

My server link that returns json result.

```
    $scope.data= [
        { id: 1, name:"D1" },
        { id: 2, name:"D2" },
        { id: 3, name:"D3" },
        { id: 4, name:"D4" }
    ];
```

I am using $resource in angularjs controller like this:

```
app.controller("MydataListController", function($scope, $resource, $http){
    var dataquery = $resource("http://192.6.4.44/DataProvider/Search/",
        {  },
        { get: {method: "JSONP"} , params:{ term: "port" } });

    $scope.result = dataquery.get();
    console.log($scope.result);
```

});

But my **$scope.result** retuns like this:

```
Resource {$promise: Object, $resolved: false, $get: function, $save:
```

Answer (score 0):

Since $resource makes an asynchronous call, you need to pass a handler function to the get method, like so:

```
app.controller("MydataListController", function($scope, $resource, $http){
    var dataquery = $resource("http://192.6.4.44/DataProvider/Search/",
        {  },
        { get: {method: "JSONP"} , params:{ term: "port" } });

    dataquery.get({}, function(data) {
        $scope.result = data;
        console.log($scope.result);
    });
});
```

FYI: I haven't tested this code!